# Sending Request and Get Response From a PHP file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a php file on my server that takes two argument and register my users.Can any one tell me the easiest way to send request to that gile and get response?

**My php file returns integer value like 1 for successful registration.2 For User exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSURLConnection` with `NSMutableURLRequest` or `NSURLRequest`

The class that you make the request in should implement this code.

```
-(void)yourMethod
{
// assume your append is a string of format ?key1=value1&key2=value2

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.stackoverflow.com/myPhpFile.php%@", append];

    urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    [urlRequest release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:
                         NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // check string for successful registration

    [string release];
}
```

You don't need to use https if your site does not have an SSL certificate.

Comment: responseData WHAT IS IT?IN HERE :   NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:
                         NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: sorry,  I edited my code.  I had been appending my data into a mutable data object because my packets were to big.  It should be initWithData:data .... I will edit the answer

Comment: It's working with a silly bug.When i click my signup button the yourMethod get fires and returns null.It don't affect my database actually.And from the second clik it register.It returns null in the first click.Any Idea what's going on?

Comment: Neither of the methods above have a return value.  What is null?  The string in - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data   ??

You should disable the button while awaiting a response and use the response to resume application activities.
There are other responses the URLConnection class can get, so implement some of them and log the errors to see if the connection fails

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response